# elasticsearch query_string and term search syntax

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to search for `query_string` that contains `Bob` and an `Industry_Type_ID` of either `8` OR `9`.

I am getting a parse error: `Parse Failure [No parser for element [Industry_Type_ID]]`

```
{
    "query" : {
        "query_string":{"query":"Bob"},
        "terms" : {
            "Industry_Type_ID" : [ "8", "9" ],
            "minimum_match" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it using [bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query.html) with two `must` clauses:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "query_string":{"query":"Bob"}
                },
                {
                    "terms" : {
                        "Industry_Type_ID" : [ "8", "9" ],
                        "minimum_match" : 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```